# Is there a delegate available for properties in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following class:

```
class TestClass {
  public void SetValue(int value) { Value = value; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I can do

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass();
Action<int> setAction = tc.SetValue;
setAction.Invoke(12);
```

which is all good. Is it possible to do the same thing using the property instead of the method? Preferably with something built in to .net.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could create the delegate using reflection :

```
Action<int> valueSetter = (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), tc, tc.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetSetMethod());
```

or create a delegate to an anonymous method which sets the property;

```
Action<int> valueSetter = v => tc.Value = v;
```

Edit: used wrong overload for CreateDelegate(), need to use the one that takes and object as target. Fixed.

Comment: Given that C# is supposed to be my first language I really wish I'd understand this stuff (creating a delegate using reflection) - sounds great

Comment: And for .net 2.0 one could do Action<int> valueSetter = delegate(int value) { tc.Value = value; }

Comment: @Robert, you can target .Net 2.0 using the C# 3.0 compiler, there's no reason to stick to the C# 2.0 compiler ;)

Comment: FWIW, I was curious, and benchmarked your two approaches given above (except since I'm targeting .Net 2.0, I used Action<int> valueSetter = delegate(int v) { tc.Value = v; }; instead of the lambda you gave).  The tradeoff you get for compile-time type- and name-checking  (the anonymous delegate / lambda version) is that it takes twice as long, because the code calls a delegate which calls the property setter.  The first approach directly calls the property setter, so while you don't get compile-time checking, you get twice the speed, which for my particular approach is significant.

Answer (score 12):

There are three ways of doing this; the first is to use GetGetMethod()/GetSetMethod() and create a delegate with Delegate.CreateDelegate. The second is a lambda (not much use for reflection!) [i.e. x=>x.Foo]. The third is via Expression (.NET 3.5).

The lambda is the easiest ;-p

```
    class TestClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<TestClass, int> lambdaGet = x => x.Value;
        Action<TestClass, int> lambdaSet = (x, val) => x.Value = val;

        var prop = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty("Value");
        Func<TestClass, int> reflGet = (Func<TestClass, int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Func<TestClass, int>), prop.GetGetMethod());
        Action<TestClass, int> reflSet = (Action<TestClass, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Action<TestClass, int>), prop.GetSetMethod());
    }
```

To show usage:

```
        TestClass foo = new TestClass();
        foo.Value = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Via property: " + foo.Value);

        lambdaSet(foo, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Via lambda: " + lambdaGet(foo));

        reflSet(foo, 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Via CreateDelegate: " + reflGet(foo));
```

Note that if you want the delegate pointing to the specific instance, you can use closures for the lambda, or the overload of CreateDelegate that accepts and instance.

Comment: btw, I haven't posted an Expression example, as it tends to be verbose. However, some Expression posts are on my blog: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/search/label/expression

Comment: Thnak you very much for this easy to understand example!

Answer (score 3):

Properties are really wrappers around methods in .Net, so using reflection you should be able to get the delegate (set_PROPERTY and get_PROPERTY) and then execute them...

See [System.Reflection.PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(VS.85).aspx)

If has two methods which you can use to get/ set the value - GetGetMethod and GetSetMethod.

So you could write:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof (TestClass).GetProperty ("Value");

var setMethod = property.GetSetMethod (); // This will return a MethodInfo class.
```

Comment: Even though the C# specification reserves methods get_P and set_P for any property P, it does not require implementations to use these   methods for properties. This makes it an implementation detail. Do not rely on undocumented implementation details.

Comment: By using the PropertyInfo class and the GetGet/SetMethod it's no longer an implementation problem. It's part of the framework at that point.