# How can I get delegates to property accessors from a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, properties, delegates

I'm currently building a node editor ([as in Blender](http://orange.blender.org/wp-content/themes/orange/images/blog/noodles.jpg)) and am having trouble getting delegates to property accessors from a generic type. So far the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289980/is-there-a-delegate-available-for-properties-in-c) has brought me closest, but I'm having trouble that I think is specifically related to the type of object being generic.

For reference, a "Node" is synonymous with an object, and a "Port" is synonymous with a property.

This is the offending code, which is part of the `Node` class. The `NodePort` class is an attribute that may be set on properties to provide details (such as the human-readable name, and data-flow direction) for the property.

```
public void SetTarget<T>(T Target)
{
    //TODO: Finish clearing old IOs (if any)
    Inputs.Clear();
    Outputs.Clear();

    //Keep track of the current target of this node.
    ThisTarget = Target;

    PropertyInfo[] pinfo = Target.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in pinfo)
    {
        Attribute[] attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property);
        foreach (Attribute attribute in attrs)
        {
            // If the property has a NodePort attribute, it's specifically requesting to be available as a port on the node.
            if (attribute is NodePort)
            {
                NodePort PortDetails = (NodePort)attribute;

                if (PortDetails.Direction == NodePort.NodePortDirection.PORT_INPUT)
                {
                    // This line throws an ArgumentException, and the only message is "Error binding to target method."
                    NodeInput<T>.SetValue Setter = (NodeInput<T>.SetValue)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(NodeInput<T>.SetValue), (T)Target, property.GetSetMethod());
                    AddInput(Setter, PortDetails.CommonName);
                }
                else if (PortDetails.Direction == NodePort.NodePortDirection.PORT_OUTPUT)
                {
                    // Same exception here.
                    NodeOutput<T>.GetValue Getter = (NodeOutput<T>.GetValue)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(NodeOutput<T>.GetValue), (T)Target, property.GetGetMethod());
                    AddOutput(Getter, PortDetails.CommonName);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`NodeOutput<T>.GetValue` and `NodeInput<T>.SetValue` are defined as such:

```
public delegate T GetValue();
public delegate void SetValue(T value);
```

...in `NodeOutput` and `NodeInput` respectively.

Does anyone have any experience with creating delegates for property accessors? Any idea how it may be different when the type in question is generic?

Comment: Can any type of property be decorated with *NodePort*?

Comment: Yes. `NodePort` can be applied to any property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a type mismatch here.  In the first of your exception lines, `setter` is declared to be of type `NodeInput<T>`, which means it is a method that takes T and returns void.  But the method that you are assigning to `setter` is property.GetSetMethod(), which will be a method that takes property.PropertyType and returns void.  This will cause an exception unless by good fortune the property.PropertyType is the same as T.  Similarly for `getter` on the second of your exception lines.

I suspect you can't handle this using generics, because you don't know property.PropertyType at compile time, so you can't pass that type as a generic parameter (because generic parameters must be specified at compile time, unless you use type.MakeGenericType).

Comment: That was supposed to be the purpose of Delegate.CreateDelegate - it accepts a type (typeof(NodeInput<T>.GetSetter)), a target (Target) and a MethodInfo (property.GetSetMethod()). The MethodInfo for GetSetMethod() just describes a simple setter. void Set(T). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod(VS.71).aspx

Comment: But the MethodInfo for GetSetMethod doesn't match void Set(T).  It matches void Set(property.PropertyType).  Catch property.GetSetMethod into a temporary variable and examine it in the debugger.  For example, suppose T has a property Foo of type int.  Then when, in your loop, property is the PropertyInfo for Foo, property.GetSetMethod will be of type int => void, not type T => void, because the Foo property setter takes a int, not a T.  The set method is *declared* on T, but does not *accept* a T.

Comment: Alright I see, yes, you're right. So I guess the question now is, how do I instantiate a generic object off a System.Type? I have the System.Type from property, but I don't know how to use that to create an instance of a generic (in this case my delegate setter).

Comment: To construct a generic type, you'd use Type.MakeGenericType().  E.g. typeof(NodeInput<>).MakeGenericType(propType).  But although this instantiates the type, it still gives you no way of referring to the instance in a strong-typed way *at compile time*.  Ultimately, because you don't find out until runtime whether T.Foo is an int or a string, you can't capture this in a compile-time-typed instance of a generic.  But consider: could you actually call such a delegate in a strong-typed way anyway?  What type of argument would you pass?  You may be forced down the weak typing route anyway...

Comment: Ah hah! After some tinkering, I got it working perfectly. Thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

To create a delegate to the property accessors, you just use `GetGetMethod` and `GetSetMethod`; can you explain where it is breaking down?

A simplified example:

```
using System;
class Foo<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Foo<int> { Value = 123 };
        var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
        Func<Foo<int>, int> getter = (Func<Foo<int>, int>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(
              typeof(Func<Foo<int>, int>), prop.GetGetMethod());
        int x = getter(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Action<Foo<int>, int> setter = (Action<Foo<int>, int>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(
              typeof(Action<Foo<int>, int>), prop.GetSetMethod());
        setter(obj, 321);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
    }
}
```

Note that to handle things just on `object` there are tricks involving base-classes etc - or perhaps consider things like [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx); similar performance, but much simpler, since you just use `PropertyDescriptor` and `object` (after enabling it):

```
var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)["Value"];
object val = prop.GetValue(prop);
prop.SetValue(prop, 321);
```

A last option is `Expression`; I cover various tricks for property access in `Expression` in [this series](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/search/label/expression).